# Is it correct to say "The piggy tricked the wolf into falling into the hole"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

I am not sure how to use the structure "**A tricked B into *doing something***".

**Was B willing to do that thing at first?**

This is the example in the dictionary "[He tricked me into lending him £100.](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/trick-into-doing#trickintodoing2_e)".

That means "**I was willing to give my money to him at first**" and I might know his bad intention after that.

This is a story

> A wolf wants to eat a piggy. The piggy digs a hole and covers it with
> some leaves to make it as if there is no hole.
>
> The piggy stands on the other side of the hole and says to the wolf,
> "come on! come closer". The wolf comes closer and he happens to fall
> into the hole.

Does this sentence "**The piggy tricked the wolf into falling into the hole**" make sense?

**Was the wolf willing to fall into the hole?**

Or we might say "**The piggy tricked the wolf into coming closer to the covered hole to make it fall into it**".

Comment: The question phrased in the title is good, but I would avoid repeating 'into' with '*down* the hole'. But the wolf was not willing to go there: it didn't know the hole was there. The last sentence in the post isn't very good.

Comment: I think there's nothing remotely awkward about repeating ***into*** in such contexts. Hey! - I wouldn't have a problem with *She tricked him into going into the garden and falling into the pond* (I'd *probably* change either or both of the last two from ***into*** to plain ***in***, but it's no big deal either way). But OP's *final* example is stylistically very weak - primarily because of those two instances of ***it*** with two different referents. But as to the actual question here - if you're tricked into doing something, obviously that's not "voluntary"

Comment: Someone you trick into doing something is not doing it willingly. The example from the dictionary does not state anything about what you were willing to do. Maybe you didn't want to lend him ANY money; maybe you were willing to lend him 20 pounds.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work for me.

When you trick somebody into doing something, you mislead them into doing the thing purposely, not accidentally. (it's about intention, rather than willingness).

Comment: So, what should I say then?

Comment: In the example given, the wolf certainly advanced willingly and purposefully, and falling into the hole was simply the result.  It would sound much weirder to say "the piggy tricked the wolf into advancing", since advancing seems like the wolf's desire anyway.